# Apache alias from sub domain to domains article

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I wonder is it possible to make an alias from sub domain, let's say http://sub.domain.com, to http://domain.com/some-article. When user types in address bar sub.domain.com, he should see that article(address in address bar should be the same sub domain, so I think redirect its not what I need). Any ideas?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK this is done with DNS, not the web server (if anyone knows that I am wrong feel free to correct me). Also this should probably be posted on serverfault, not stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, it's called [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Apache ServerAlias only covers a hostname and not a fully qualified URI.

In the above example you should use mod_rewrite, making sure to omit the R flag since you don't want to redirect i.e provide a 30X status code in the response.

So in the above example you could have the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias sub.domain.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /some-article [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http:/domain.com/some-article$1 [L]
...
</VirtualHost>
```